# getAttribute resulting in java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

So I'm learning Servlet and JSP and I'm trying to send a String name to my jsp using RequestDispatcher but I'm getting java.lang.NullPointerException

DemoServlet.java

```
package com.shubhankar;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
@WebServlet("/DemoServlet")
public class DemoServlet extends HttpServlet {
    
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        String name ="Harmless";
        request.setAttribute("label", "Harmless");
        RequestDispatcher rd= request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
        
    }   
}
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%

        String name=request.getAttribute("label").toString();
        out.println(name);
%>
</body>
</html>
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNstL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use setAttribute (and getAttribute) when you need to pass objects around across many servlets (or other components) handling the same request.

Can you please try using setAttribute in your servlet and fetch the parameter using getParameter in the jsp

```
request.setAttribute("name", "Harmless");

above code in servlet.

and try to fetch in jsp as below
<%
  request.getParamter("name");
%>
```

Comment: hey when I add `request.setParameter("name", "Harmless");`in Servlet I get this error `The method setParameter(String, String) is undefined for the type HttpServletRequest`

Comment: try request.setAttribute("name","Harmless") in servlet

Comment: it shows the same error as servlet ie can't use getParameter with request

Comment: ```
request.getSession().setAttribute("name", "Harmless");

above code in servlet.

and try to fetch in jsp as below
<%
 session.getAttribute("name");
%> 

```

Comment: I'm getting is null in name on my jsp page

Comment: what is the attribute you are setting from servlet. i just gave an example request.getSession().setAttribute("name","Harmless")

Comment: Yeah I too set the same attributes as `setAttribute("name","Harmless") `

Comment: Here is my output:https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDnKo.png I

Comment: Hope you are calling the servlet which is redirecting to index.jsp. http://localhost:10311/JSTLDemo/DemoServlet